# What does the Hulk's clap do?

Tags: comics, marvel, the-incredible-hulk

When the Hulk claps it appears to generate enough force to send people flying.  How does this work - is it wind due to the air being pushed out from between his hands, a sonic boom from the sound of the hands meeting, or something else entirely?

Comment: It takes a brave man to ask the Hulk about his clap.

Comment: painful urination, discharge, and soreness in the affected area.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's the same thing that's so destructive with bombs and other explosions at close range, even without shrapnel.  In effect, it causes a concussive wave (also called a shock wave).

[Wikipedia explains it nicely](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave).

> A shock wave (also called shock front or simply "shock") is a type of
>   propagating disturbance. Like an ordinary wave, it carries energy and
>   can propagate through a medium (solid, liquid, gas or plasma) or in
>   some cases in the absence of a material medium, through a field such
>   as the electromagnetic field. Shock waves are characterized by an
>   abrupt, nearly discontinuous change in the characteristics of the
>   medium.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shock_wave) Across a shock there is always an extremely rapid rise in
>   pressure, temperature and density of the flow. In supersonic flows,
>   expansion is achieved through an expansion fan. A shock wave travels
>   through most media at a higher speed than an ordinary wave.

A sonic boom is another form of concussive wave, so yes, they are similar.

It's a different phenomena than wind, which involves a more steady movement of air.

A better analogy might be a comparison of a wave in the water to the flow of a stream.  With a wave, the medium through which it travels doesn't move much.  It's a bit easier to visualize the difference (at least for me.)

[This article](http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/earth/oceanography/wave-energy.htm) describes how waves work.

Comment: Ultra-Sonic boom is correct answer...