# Has Hulk ever used this power in a battle before?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, she-hulk-attorney-at-law

In "She-Hulk : Attorney at law", in the fight scene between Hulk and She-Hulk, Hulk does the power clap thing that knocks She-Hulk away.

I wonder if he ever used that in a battle before against enemies or anyone.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15197/what-does-the-hulks-clap-do

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hulk used his 'thunderclap' in the MCU movie *The Incredible Hulk* (2008)

In [comics](https://www.incrediblehulkonline.com/torchthunderclap.jpg), [animation](https://c.tenor.com/zO700DCSlVIAAAAd/hulk-thunder-clap.gif) and [video-games](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hrNS5so2ZQo) it's been a fairly regular feature of his arsenal [since the 1960s](https://comicvine.gamespot.com/a/uploads/original/10/103503/3952300-thunderclap.png)